Altair sorting not working properly on faceted chart
I have some faceted bar graphs displaying the amounts of different colors in different paintings.
base = alt.Chart(df).mark_bar().encode(
        x=alt.X(
            'color',
            title='',
        ),
        y=alt.Y(
            'amount',
            title='',
            ),
        color=alt.Color('color',scale= alt.Scale(domain=rp,range=rph))
    ).properties(
        width=80,
        height=80
    ).facet(
        facet='TITLE',
        columns=5
    )

Here's the first row:

I want to sort each graph descending on the x-axis, so I add:
x=alt.X(
  'color',
  title='',
  sort='-y'
)

Here's the result:

The 2nd and 5th graphs almost sort correctly, but not quite, and the same for the 1st and 3rd graphs but they're ascending for some reason. what would cause this strange behavior? Is it something to do with faceting?

Does it work as expected if you remove just the facetting part? And are you able to post a sample the data to create df that reproduces the problem? You can see an example of a reproducible snippet here

Does adding .resolve_scale(x='independent') produce desired output?
import altair as alt

base = (
    alt.Chart(df)
    .mark_bar()
    .encode(
        x=alt.X(
            "color",
            title="",
            sort="-y",
        ),
        y=alt.Y(
            "amount",
            title="",
        ),
        color=alt.Color("color", scale=alt.Scale(domain=rp, range=rph)),
    )
    .properties(width=80, height=80)
    .facet(facet="TITLE", columns=5)
    .resolve_scale(x="independent")
)

